# WebApi deserialize JSON array of objects with dynamic parameter names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a JSON object with this structure:

```
{
    "customLineItemParameters": [
    {"paramName1": "value1"}, 
    {"paramName2": "value2"}, 
    {"paramName3": "value3"}
    ]
}
```

My model property looks like this:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> CustomLineItemParameters { get; set; }
```

When trying to deserialise the JSON object, I get a list of three tuples, but the tuple values are empty:

```
[0] -> {(, )}
[1] -> {(, )}
[2] -> {(, )}
```

How should my model look in order to properly deserialize the json? (I can't change the json structure).

Comment: you post method are you using Json.strngify?

Comment: Try `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or`Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: @Yashveer i use postman for posting.

Comment: @Developer same issue with KeyValuePair, already tried it. For Dictionary<string,string> the dictionary is null on deserialisation.

Comment: Yeah my bad. For Dictionary, the it should be json object not array. And for KeyValuePair, I think the `key` and `value` properties are required, notbsure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> CustomLineItemParameters { get; set; }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you know why Tuple<string, string> or  KeyValuePair<string, string> don't work?

Comment: Tuples are just regular objects. The default JSON serializer would inflate values in their `Item1` and `Item2` properties if the incoming object had them. The same applies to `KeyValuePair`. The `Dictionary` object is an exception. I think it implements an interface but I can't tell you for sure.